# Grouping an Ext JS 4.0.2a Grid on a Column that Contains a null value

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs, extjs4, store

I have a model called 'Students' where one of the fields 'Team' is defined as:

```
{
  name: 'team',
  type: 'int',
  useNull: true
}
```

Now I want to group on this field using:

```
Ext.getStore('Students').group('team');
```

And it's throwing this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of null".

I tested if the absence of nulls fixes the issue by filling the nulls in with empty strings and the error went away.

How can I fix this so I'm able to group nulls into their own group? Without throwing the error?

Comment: why do you need to use nulls? they slow your database queries down and in this scenario an empty string would suffice

Comment: Does Ext.StoreMgr.get('Students') work?

Answer (score 1):

You can set convert setting to team field in model.

```
{
  name: 'team',
  type: 'int',
  useNull: true,
  convert: function(value) {
    return: value ? value : 0;
  }
}
```

then you can use int zero instead of null.

Comment: Sadly this fix doesn't work for me, the foreign key value on my save cant be sent to the server as 0.